# Installing Odoo on Mac raises gevent error

Tags: python, odoo, cython

I'm following [this tutorial](https://douno.net/2018/06/06/how-to-install-odoo-on-mac-os-using-homebrew/) to install Odoo 15 on Mac, but I'm getting this error when running `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef load_traceback
      cdef Waiter
      cdef wait
      cdef iwait
      cdef reraise
      cpdef GEVENT_CONFIG
            ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
      src/gevent/_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd:181:6: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
```

I have found several documents addressing cython errors, but none addressing the specific exception I'm getting.

Comment: Have you tried making the change that it suggests? (It looks like the current version of gevent already makes that change https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/5858d226045f701deb8e4b49c03db4cab63053d6/src/gevent/_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd#L182)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo 15 currently seems to be incompatible with Python 3.10.

You can get rid of that error by upgrading gevent/greenlet to newer versions in the requirements file. I've successfully tried gevent 21.12.0 and greenlet 1.1.3, BUT then you'll run into more trouble due to changes in the Python collections package.
[Here](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1801) is a link to the issue regarding the gevent error for reference.

Downgrade to Python 3.9.0 for the moment to continue with the installation.

Answer (score 7):

this solved it for me:

```
pip install pip setuptools wheel Cython==3.0.0a10
pip install gevent==20.9.0 --no-build-isolation
```

if some problem with psycopg2 occurs, run this: (you can change 2.8.6 to 2.8.5 depending on what you need)

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"

pip3 install psycopg2==2.8.6
```

you might also need

```
brew install libpq --build-from-source                                                                                      brew install openssl

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"
```

and if reportlab raises an installation error, try this:

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" pip install reportlab==3.5.55
```

Comment: it seems like there is a "export" missing in the last "try this:" and a line break.  After those changes, it works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

using `gevent==21.12.0` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Can you add some detail? We like to see fully described solutions.