# Error while trying to install odoo15 requirements.txt on M1

Tags: python, macos, pip, odoo, python-wheel

I am trying to install the requirements for odoo15 on my MBP M1 Pro running MacOS Ventura 13.0 in my virtual environment running python 3.10.8

but I keep getting the following error:

```
build/temp.macosx-12-arm64-cpython-310/_openssl.c:575:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
      #include <openssl/opensslv.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
...
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib'
      ld: library not found for -lssl
      clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
...
Failed to build cryptography psycopg2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Now, I have already spent a lot of time researching and it seems that openssl might be the problem here

I have already install openssl via brew, it is running the newest version, as suggested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/8769)

I have installed the newest version of pip as suggested in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59441794/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-cryptography-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-i)

Edit: I have now also tried setting these flags as suggested in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073246/using-python3-on-macos-as-default-but-pip-still-get-using-python-2-7/67430399#67430399):

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

I have also retried everything in another venv using Python version 3.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67430399/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+opensslv.h+file+not+found

Comment: @phd thanks for the tip, unfortunately it did not work out

Comment: To anyone wondering, this solved all the problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667667/installing-odoo-on-mac-raises-gevent-error